# how to use rollup to parse cucumber feature files and backing step definition files

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

I have the following rollup plugin that will include `.feature` files

```js
export const cucumberRollupPlugin: PluginImpl<CucumberOptions> = pluginOptions => {
  let options: CucumberOptions = {
    ...{
      include: '**/*.feature',
      cwd: process.cwd(),
    },
    ...pluginOptions,
  };

  let filter = createFilter(options);

  let plugin: Plugin = {
    name: 'bigtest-cucumber',
    async transform(code, id) {
      if (!filter(id)) {
        return;
      }

      let parser = new GherkinParser({ code, uri: id, rootDir: options.cwd });

      let result = await parser.parse();

      let esm = dataToEsm(result, { namedExports: false });

      // TODO: add sourcemap support
      let transformResult: TransformResult = { code: esm };

      return transformResult;
    },
  };

  return plugin;
};
```

The problem I have is that to make the feature files work, there are step definition files that actually contain the functionality.  So a feature file might look like this

```
Feature: Visit career guide page in career.guru99.com
Scenario: Visit career.guru99.com
Given: I browse to career.guru99.com
```

And a step definition file might look like this:

```js
import { Given, When, Then from 'cucumber';
import assert from 'assert';
import{ driver } from '../support/web_driver';

Given(/^browse to web site "([^"]*)"$/, async function(url) {
    return driver.get(url);
});
```

The problem I have with rollup is that there are no import statements for either the step definition files.  The way cucumber-js works is that these files are found at runtime.

I think I need to generate an `index.js` that looks like this to cover the step definitions.

```js
import from './step_definition_1';
import from './step_definition_2';
import from './step_definition_3';
```

Where would this fit in the rollup pipeline to generate this file so it can get pulled into the rollup pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`this.emitFile`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#thisemitfileemittedfile-emittedchunk--emittedasset--string) to manually process the `.feature` files and include them in the output. Call `this.emitFile` for each `.feature` file in the [`buildStart`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#buildstart) hook (each emitted file will get processed through the `transform` hook you wrote).

Here's an example that uses the [`globby`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/globby) package (which expands a glob to an array of file paths) to get the file path of each `.feature` file to pass to `this.emitFile`:

```js
import globby from 'globby'

export const cucumberRollupPlugin: PluginImpl<CucumberOptions> = pluginOptions => {
  let options: CucumberOptions = {
    include: '**/*.feature',
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    ...pluginOptions,
  };

  let filter = createFilter(options);

  let plugin: Plugin = {
    name: 'bigtest-cucumber',
    async buildStart({ include, cwd }) {
      const featureFilePaths = await globby(include, { cwd });

      for (const featureFilePath of featureFilePaths) {
        this.emitFile({
          type: 'chunk',
          id: featureFilePath
        });
      }
    },
    async transform(code, id) {
      if (!filter(id)) {
        return;
      }

      let parser = new GherkinParser({ code, uri: id, rootDir: options.cwd });

      let result = await parser.parse();

      let esm = dataToEsm(result, { namedExports: false });

      // TODO: add sourcemap support
      let transformResult: TransformResult = { code: esm };

      return transformResult;
    },
  };

  return plugin;
};
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the this.emitFile method and befor that lookup the files via glob or anything else inside your plugin

```
{
  plugins: [typescript(),{
  name: "emit-additional-files",
  async transform(code,id) {
    //id === fileName
    //code === fileContent
    // inspect code or id here then use path.resolve() and fs.readdir to find additional files
    this.emitFile()

  }
}]
}
```

Comment: these could be typescript files that would require going through a typescript plugin themselves.

Where would the `emitFile` go?  Before transform?